# What causes an open ground on a wall outlet when I turn on the light switch to the ceiling lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring

We just moved into this 1960s era home.  In the living room, when the light switch is "off", the wall outlets test ok (both amber lights are lit) using a 3 prong outlet tester.  However, when I flip the switch to turn on the ceiling light, the 3-prong outlet tester indicates open ground (the middle amber light stays lit, the amber light on the right goes off).  I actually see the amber light on the right edge of the outlet tester go off when I flip the switch to turn on the ceiling light.

What could be causing this?  Could the neutral wire and the ground wire be reversed on the light switch? Is this a dangerous condition?

Answer (score 1):

Ok John this probably not the answer you want to hear but, using a tester as you describe is fine for checking for problems, now is the time to call a electrician to identify and resolve the wiring issue.... most not all homes built around your homes era did not have grounded outlets. Please get a referral and try to avoid fixed price franchise electricians. God Bless Big Jim